# Analyse Magento performance

Tags: mysql, database-performance, magento-1.8

I've a shop based on magento 1.8 and i consider magento slow and "heavy".

I'm analyse several points trying to get some conclusions.

**I executed this command (at linux web server):**
mysqladmin -u root -p version

**and get this result:**
Threads: 6  Questions: 708190020  Slow queries: 3202  Opens: 60678  Flush tables                                                       : 1  Open tables: 512  Queries per second avg: 583.301

How can i interpret the parameter Questions and Slow Queries?
This result is poor?

Answer (score 0):

583 QPS is "high" -- perhaps 85th percentile.  Is that good or bad?  It depends.  You seem to feel, for other reasons, that is bad.

3K/708M slow queries -- extremely low.  So, I don't think you have any missing indexes or poorly formulated queries -- either because of Magento or your use of it.  But...  You probably have an unreasonably high `long_query_time`: 10 is typical, but 1 is better.  Please change that (`SET @@GLOBAL.long_query_time = 1`).  Also, have the slowlog turned on (see the manual for the details for your version of MySQL).  Then we can see if there are some naughty queries.

The rest don't say much.

I don't know Magento, so I can't say whether the high QPS is its fault, or the way you have designed your application using it.  If you provide RAM size, `SHOW VARIABLES;`, and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`, I will look for things that would indicate sloppiness on the part of Magento.  It may also bring out some other red flags.